# how to create multi level partition in hive using sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

I need to create hive table having three Partitions year/month/day using Sqoop. I have checked **--hive-partition-key** and **--hive-partition-value** in sqoop. using these parameters I have created partition **year** like this   `--hive-partition-key year --hive-partition-value '2016'`
My question is how to pass multiple values for partition-key and partition-value to create partitions like year/month/day.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:7432/test_db \
  --driver org.postgresql.Driver --username pgadmin --password pgadmin@1234 \
  --table user1  \
  --fields-terminated-by '\001' \
  --lines-terminated-by '\012' \
  --hcatalog-database test \
  --hcatalog-table user1 \
  --hcatalog-partition-keys year,month,day \
  --hcatalog-partition-values '2016,08,15' \
  --verbose
```

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: NoSuchObjectException(message:test.user1 table not found)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:97)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:51)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureHCat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:343)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureImportOutputFormat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:783)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.configureOutputFormat(ImportJobBase.java:98)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:259)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: NoSuchObjectException(message:test.user1 table not found)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:34980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:34948)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:34879)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1201)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getTable(HCatUtil.java:180)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:105)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:86)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:95)
        ... 14 more
```

Updated command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:7432/test_db \
  --driver org.postgresql.Driver --username pgadmin --password pgadmin@1234 \
  --table user1  \
  --create-hcatalog-table \
  --hcatalog-table user1 \
  --hcatalog-partition-keys year,month,day \
  --hcatalog-partition-values '2016,08,15' \
  --verbose
```

Error after updated command

```
16/08/17 05:53:20 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: Executing external HCatalog CLI process with args :-f,/tmp/hcat-script-1471413200625
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: MismatchedTokenException(10!=288)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.primitiveType(HiveParser.java:39530)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.type(HiveParser.java:38772)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.colType(HiveParser.java:38522)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:38222)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:36445)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4864)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities:         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
16/08/17 05:53:24 INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: FAILED: ParseException line 3:15 mismatched input ',' expecting ( near 'varchar' in primitive type specificat
16/08/17 05:53:25 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@326de728
16/08/17 05:53:25 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: HCat exited with status 64
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.executeExternalHCatProgram(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:1129)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.launchHCatCli(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:1078)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.createHCatTable(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:625)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureHCat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:340)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureImportOutputFormat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:783)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.configureOutputFormat(ImportJobBase.java:98)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:259)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Comment: as you have hardcoded partition values like, 2016,08,15 
how to code, in case of i have dynamic partition? @Mahebub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Sqoop to import data into a multi-key partitioned Hive table, you can use the `hcatalog-table` [feature](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_sqoop_hcatalog_integration)

For instance, in your case, you could use something like this:

```
(...) --hcatalog-table <your_table_name> --hcatalog-partition-keys year,month,day
 --hcatalog-partition-values 2016,07,01
```

According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_new_command_line_options):

> These two options are used to specify multiple static partition
>   key/value pairs. In the prior releases, --hive-partition-key and
>   --hive-partition-value options were used to specify the static partition key/value pair, but only one level of static partition keys
>   could be provided. The options --hcatalog-partition-keys and
>   --hcatalog-partition-values allow multiple keys and values to be provided as static partitioning keys. Multiple option values are to be
>   separated by , (comma). For example, if the hive partition keys for
>   the table to export/import from are defined with partition key names
>   year, month and date and a specific partition with year=1999,
>   month=12, day=31 is the desired partition, then the values for the two
>   options will be as follows:
>
> --hcatalog-partition-keys year,month,day
>   --hcatalog-partition-values 1999,12,31

Comment: I tried this but I am getting error  Caused by: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.user1 table not found)

Comment: What are you using to launch the sqoop import? Oozie?

Comment: The name of the database is `test` or `test_db`? In the URL you used the second one, in the hcatalog-database you used the first one.

Comment: In postgresql database name is test_db. While importing to hdfs i am changing name of database. It works fine with hive-import. for hcatalog I tried with same database name but still same problem.

Comment: Could you add the option `--create-hcatalog-table` to the Sqoop command? By default, HCatalog tables are assumed to exist in Sqoop.

Comment: Mmmm, could you edit your question adding the error log after the use of the hcatalog command? Maybe another user can detect the error more quickly.

Comment: I'm reading the updated part of the question, did you write `--create-hcatalog-table`? or `- –create-hcatalog-table`? In the query it seems to be the second one (note the space after the first dash)

Comment: I have updated question. its `--create-hcatalog-table`.

Comment: Tried partition values without quotes but still same error.

Comment: From the exception you're getting I think that somehow Sqoop is unable to launch HCatalog. I would verify if HCatalog can be executed (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+InstallHCat#HCatalogInstallHCat-HCatalogInstalledwithHive), but I can't really know the real reason for that exception. Although it's clear (from the documentation) that the way to create a multi-level partition in Hive is by means of using HCatalog, I think this exception you're having would be worth asking in another question. Maybe another user could help you to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

we need to implement this in steps.at this Updated command: mark above you are doing two things.

creating fresh table and sqooping data ,As per my observation this will not work at a time as  we have to create multilevel partitions using sqoop.

So first create just create ddl using hcatalogue to support multilevel partitioning..

step 1:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin \
--username xxxx \
--password yyyy \
--query  'select EMPNO,ENAME,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM from  t_test_emp  where  $CONDITIONS AND 1=2' \
--create-hcatalog-table \
--hcatalog-database db1 \
--hcatalog-table test_part1 \
--hcatalog-partition-keys  DEPTNO,JOB \
--hcatalog-partition-values  1,1 \
-m 1
```

step 2:
Now insert data:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:  \
--username xxxx  \
--password yyyy \
--table t_test_emp \
--columns EMPNO,DEPTNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM \
--hcatalog-database db1 \
--hcatalog-table test_part1 \
-m 1
```

and it will work..

Comment: does it work with dynamic multikey partition too? @swapnil patil

Comment: what do you mean by multykey?we already have multikey here right i.e DEPTNO,JOB

Comment: what does thiss line do --hcatalog-partition-values  1,1 ? is it partitioning based on hardcoded value of dept=1 and job=1? what if my table has multiple dept values like 1,2..10 and i want to create partiions for each of the dept values. and for each dept partition, i want to add sub partitions...

Comment: At step 1 :dept=1 and job=1 is just given to create partition table structure
if you see --query clause 
we  are doing  where  $CONDITIONS AND 1=2  i.e. not importing any data.



At step 2 : we are doing actual import (no hard coding of partitions)